# MonoTouch for iPhone: How to move files in project around?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

After working on my project for a while, I want to rearrange my files. Specifically, I want to move some files from one folder to another. I tried to drag and drop, but nothing happens. Eventually, MonoDevelop crashed. Is this defect in MonoDevelop? Or how do it do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that drag and drop is not always reliable (and I have the same issue in Visual Studio). The best method I have found is to select the items that you want to move, select the Cut item from the Edit menu (or context menu), select the folder that you want to move them to and select the Paste item from the Edit menu.

Comment: Thank you very much for the workaround, which works. By the way, I never ran into this kind of problem in Visual Studio (over many years).

Comment: I use this solution too. If you're using subversion, cut/paste also handles the svn commands required to move files around